# Why does tsc report that SomeType has no index signature?

Tags: typescript

```
type Valid = 'A' | 'B'
type SomeType = { [index in Valid]: string }

const x: SomeType = {
    A: 'foo',
    B: 'foo',
};

let idx = 'A';

const v1 = x[idx];
```

Running tsc on the above snippet gives error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'SomeType' has no index signature`.

Has `SomeType` not been provided with a signature here:
`type SomeType = { [index in Valid]: string }`?

Comment: Which typescript version are you using?

Comment: I am just curios, would this error have been more suggestive: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SomeType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SomeType'.` (I am working on a compiler change to make this the message for the error above)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The first sentence of the revised error message (`Element implicitly...type 'SomeType'`) makes the problem clearer. The second sentence (`No index...type 'SomeType'`) is still liable to be misinterpreted -- there is an index signature with parameter type string on `SomeType` -- right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because typescript will only allow index access (under the `noImplictAny` option) only if it can prove the access is valid. This means that `x["A"]` is valid, but `x` of a random variable of type `string` is not valid.

Typescript will also let you perform the access if the variable not typed as`string` but as a union of string literal types that can be key of the index target. So this will work as well:

```
let idx: "A" | "B" = 'A';
const v1 = x[idx];
```

Or you can use the `keyof` type operator to get a union of all possible of a type:

```
let idx: keyof SomeType = 'A';
const v1 = x[idx];
```

Or you can use `const` instead of let to force the compiler to infer a string literal type for `idx` if it does not change:

```
const idx = 'A'; // idx is of type 'A'
const v1 = x[idx];
```

Or you can use a `const` assertion to tell the compiler not to widen the literal type even for a `let` declaration (although `idx will only have one possible value)

```
let idx = 'A' as const; // idx is of type 'A'
const v1 = x[idx];
```